# Loading an encrypted website content with C# and HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, web, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

I would like to load a page content with C# and HtmlAgilityPack, but I get its encrypted version.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
string html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/mundo");
```

How should I decrypt it?

Comment: The website content from the URL you provided in your question is **not** encrypted. "_How should I decrypt it?_" Since the content is not encrypted, there is nothing to decrypt...

Comment: @elgonzo my `html` variable contains unreadable mix of characters instead of a valid html

Comment: Maybe the server sends the content compressed and for whatever reason HtmlAgilityPack fails to decompress it...? When requesting the web page content from the server, you should be able (i hope, i don't know HtmlAgilityPack) to tell the server to deliver the content uncompressed to set a specific request header field. I don't know from the top of my head, give me a minute and i can tell you the request header...

Comment: Okay, the HTTP header field i was referring to is `Accept-Encoding` (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html). Try setting it to `identity` when requesting the web page. If that doesn't work, check the HtmlAgilityPack documentation about what content compression schemes it supports and try those...

Comment: (Side note: Install Telerik Fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/fiddler). It will allow you to monitor and inspect the requests and responses between your app and the web server. Makes troubleshooting so much easier and less painful...)

Answer (score 1):

As @elgonzo stated - I added accept-encoding header and it worked! Btw, there was also a need to change encoding  to UTF8. Finally, my code looks like:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "es-ES";
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Accept-Encoding";
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

I converted to `System.Net.WebClient` as it seemed easier. Thank you, @elgonzo!

Comment: Glad that you got it working. But `client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Accept-Encoding";` doesn't make a lick of sense (look up what the User-Agent request header specifies). To set the Accept-Encoding header, something like `client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = ...acceptable encodings...;` should be used, i guess...